# Flutter Trilateration (x,y)

Tags: flutter, ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android, trilateration

I am trying to make an indoor positioning application for a room. I have 3 ibeacons. In the code below, I get rssi values from these beacons. I tried to find x and y values using them. I tried some formulas but it did not show the x and y coordinates correctly. How do I use the Trilateration Method in my code?

My code:

```
class TabScanning extends StatefulWidget {
  TabScanning({super.key});

  double x = 0, y = 0;
  @override
  _TabScanningState createState() => _TabScanningState();

}

class _TabScanningState extends State<TabScanning> {
  StreamSubscription<RangingResult>? _streamRanging;
  final _regionBeacons = <Region, List<Beacon>>{};
  final _beacons = <Beacon>[];
  final controller = Get.find<RequirementStateController>();


  double x1 = 0, y1 = 150;
  double x2 = -150, y2 = -150;
  double x3 = 150, y3 = -150;

  double d1 = 0, d2 = 0, d3 = 0;
  int rssi = 0;
  int txPower = -67;
  int N = 2;
  List<double> distance = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0];

  List<Beacon> defaultBeacons = [
    const Beacon(
      proximityUUID: '1AA10000-0A46-215F-E97E-5A966A7DEDC3',
      major: 1,
      minor: 3,
      accuracy: 0.0,
      macAddress: "",
      txPower: 0,
    ),
    const Beacon(
      proximityUUID: '1AA10000-0A46-215F-E97E-5A966A7DEDC3',
      major: 1,
      minor: 4,
      accuracy: 0.0,
      macAddress: "ss",
      txPower: 0,
    ),
    const Beacon(
      proximityUUID: '1AA10000-0A46-215F-E97E-5A966A7DEDC3',
      major: 1,
      minor: 8,
      accuracy: 0.0,
      macAddress: "",
      txPower: 0,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _beacons.addAll(defaultBeacons);

    controller.startStream.listen((flag) {
      if (flag == true) {
        initScanBeacon();
      }
    });

    controller.pauseStream.listen((flag) {
      if (flag == true) {
        //pauseScanBeacon();
      }
    });

  }

  initScanBeacon() async {
    await flutterBeacon.initializeScanning;
    if (!controller.authorizationStatusOk ||
        !controller.locationServiceEnabled ||
        !controller.bluetoothEnabled) {
      print(
          'RETURNED, authorizationStatusOk=${controller.authorizationStatusOk}, '
          'locationServiceEnabled=${controller.locationServiceEnabled}, '
          'bluetoothEnabled=${controller.bluetoothEnabled}');
      return;
    }

    final regions = <Region>[
      Region(
        identifier: 'ibeacon',
        proximityUUID: '1AA10000-0A46-215F-E97E-5A966A7DEDC3',
      ),
    ];

    if (_streamRanging != null) {
      if (_streamRanging!.isPaused) {
        _streamRanging?.resume();
        return;
      }
    }

    _streamRanging =
        flutterBeacon.ranging(regions).listen((RangingResult result) {
      print(result);
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _regionBeacons[result.region] = result.beacons;


          _beacons.forEach((existingBeacon) {
            result.beacons.forEach((newBeacon) {
              if (existingBeacon.major == newBeacon.major &&
                  existingBeacon.minor == newBeacon.minor) {            
                _beacons[_beacons.indexOf(existingBeacon)] = Beacon(
                  proximityUUID: existingBeacon.proximityUUID,
                  major: existingBeacon.major,
                  minor: existingBeacon.minor,
                  accuracy: newBeacon.accuracy,
                  rssi: newBeacon.rssi,
                  macAddress: newBeacon.macAddress,
                  txPower: newBeacon.txPower,
                );
              }
            });
          });
          _beacons.sort(_compareParameters);


         for (int i = 0; i < _beacons.length; i++) {
            rssi =_beacons[i].rssi;


            if (_beacons[i].minor == 3) {
              dist[0] = pow(10, ((txPower - rssi) / (10 * 2))) as double;
            } else if (_beacons[i].minor == 4) {
              dist[1] = pow(10, ((txPower - rssi) / (10 * 2))) as double;
            } else if (_beacons[i].minor == 8) {
              dist[2] = pow(10, ((txPower - rssi) / (10 * 2))) as double;
            }
          }

            d1 = dist[0];
            d2 = dist[1];
            d3 = dist[2];


            double a = (-2 * x1) + (2 * x2);
            double b = (-2 * y1) + (2 * y2);
            num c = pow(d1, 2) -
                pow(d2, 2) -
                pow(x1, 2) +
                pow(x2, 2) -
                pow(y1, 2) +
                pow(y2, 2);
            double d = (-2 * x2) + (2 * x3);
            double e = (-2 * y2) + (2 * y3);
            num f = pow(d2, 2) -
                pow(d3, 2) -
                pow(x2, 2) +
                pow(x3, 2) -
                pow(y2, 2) +
                pow(y3, 2);

            widget.x = (c * e - f * b);
            widget.x = widget.x / (e * a - b * d);

            widget.y = (c * d - a * f);
            widget.y = widget.y / (b * d - a * e);

        });
      }
    });
  }


  pauseScanBeacon() async {
    //_streamRanging?.pause();
    if (_beacons.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        //_beacons.clear();
      });
    }
  }

  int _compareParameters(Beacon a, Beacon b) {
    int compare = a.proximityUUID.compareTo(b.proximityUUID);
    if (compare == 0) {compare = a.major.compareTo(b.major);}
    if (compare == 0) {compare = a.minor.compareTo(b.minor);}
    return compare;
  }
}
```

I found this calculation on github. But it only shows numbers like x= 0.012........ y= -38.15........ it doesn't change much.

[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmoB7.jpg)
[myapp2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEpuR.jpg)

Comment: You say "it did not show the x and y coordinates correctly".  What specifically did the program do?  What is it about the output of the program that makes you think it is incorrect?  At what point in the execution do you believe things are going wrong?

Comment: I added my calculations and screenshots to my post. Inside the initScanBeacon method. I don't know much about programming. so I'm not sure if my code is working correctly.

Comment: You might try doing the calculations on paper manually for a sample set of input distances to see if you have a working  formula.  You can then use this same procedure to find a replacement formula if necessary.